# How to plot graph of time series without memorizing the entire series?

Tags: plot, visualization, numerical-methods

The time series grows *indefinitely*, but I want to be able to look at the plot from the beginning time t0 to the current time step t.  This means that the time scale of the plot would be *constantly shrinking*.

Of course, I can keep all the time series data, and at each time step I just re-draw the plot with the new scale.  But what if the memory is also limited?

Suppose the programmer is allowed to keep a memory array of only N numbers (they can store any number in the array they want).

How can the programmer plot a graph that retains the approximate *shape* of the true graph, despite using limited memory?

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution, which can plot an arbitrarily-long time series *without* losing sight of the beginning part.

The trick is:  when the plot reaches the right edge of the graph, re-scale the entire graph by 1/2, and put the compressed graph on the left half.  Then start plotting at the mid-point onwards.

By repeatedly doing this, the graph ends up having a "log" time-scale, where the left side is exponentially compressed, but the user can still see the "shape" of things in the distant past.

The algorithm:

```
if (t > max_t)                   // t is time index
    // compress array by 1/2
    for (i = 0 to arraySize)
        a[i] = (a[i * 2] + a[i * 2 + 1]) / 2;
    // start from mid-point
    t = arraySize / 2;
    [ re-plot the graph from 0 to 1/2 arraySize ]
else
    [ plot the next datum normally ]
    ++t
```

Example output (the error of a machine learning algorithm decreasing slowly):

[image]